# multiple search results

Tags: search

I am getting multiple results of same data.please suggest

**Search Page Code**

```
{exp:search:simple_form channels="pages|news" result_page="widgets/Widget_search_results/" search_in="everywhere" form_class="search" where="all" show_expired="yes" show_future_entries="yes"}    
  <input type="text" maxlength="100" size="18" value="" id="keywords" name="keywords">
  <input type="submit" class="submit" value="search">        
 {/exp:search:simple_form}
```

**Result Page code**

```
{exp:channel:entries {embed:_channel_params}}
<!-- Start Widget: {channel_short_name} -->
<table border="0" cellpadding="6" cellspacing="1" width="100%">
<tr>
<th>{lang:title}</th>
<th>{lang:excerpt}</th>
<th>{lang:author}</th>
<th>{lang:date}</th>
<th>{lang:total_comments}</th>
<th>{lang:recent_comments}</th>
</tr>

{exp:search:search_results switch="resultRowOne"}

<tr class="{switch}">
<td width="30%" valign="top"><b><a href="{auto_path}">{title}</a></b></td>
<td width="30%" valign="top">{excerpt}</td>
<td width="10%" valign="top"><a href="{member_path='member/index'}">{author}</a></td>
<td width="10%" valign="top">{entry_date format="%m/%d/%y"}</td>
<td width="10%" valign="top">{comment_total}</td>
<td width="10%" valign="top">{recent_comment_date format="%m/%d/%y"}</td>
</tr>

{/exp:search:search_results}

</table>
<!-- End Widget: {channel_short_name} -->
{/exp:channel:entries}
```

Answer (score 2):

Not sure why there are `channel:entries` loops in this template - I'm assuming you've inherited this site from another developer?

Start by removing the opening and closing `channel:entries` tags.

Comment: YEs i copied this code..what would be the correct syntax without Loop??

Comment: In this case, it appears you shouldn't even need the `exp:channel:entries` loop. Just delete the starting and ending tags and you should be okay, probably.